# How to use gpg to encrypt from STDIN using a symmetric cipher?

Tags: macos, encryption, gnupg

I'm trying to encrypt data from `STDIN` using `gpg`. I'm using the following:

```
echo 'plaintext' | gpg -c -o output.gpg
```

However, I see the following result:

```
gpg: problem with the agent: Inappropriate ioctl for device
gpg: error creating passphrase: Operation cancelled
gpg: symmetric encryption of '[stdin]' failed: Operation cancelled
```

How would I encrypt from `STDIN` using `gpg` and a symmetric cipher only? I am on MacOS and `GPG v2.2.13`.

Comment: Can not reproduce on arch linux with GnuPG 2.2.12. Can you tell us which `--version` of `gpg` you are using?

Comment: @confetti I'm using MacOS, if that makes a difference. GPG v2.2.13, updated the question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Many people recommend installing `pinentry-mac`, a package that isn’t maintained by the official GnuPG team. **I would recommend against it.**

A more secure alternative is to append the following lines to `~/.profile` as suggested in the [official docs](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT.html#Invoking-GPG_002dAGENT) (appending them to `~/.bashrc` didn’t work for me).

```
GPG_TTY=$(tty)
export GPG_TTY
```

Once these lines have been appended, close your terminal and the issue should be resolved.

Also, make sure you upgrade gnupg to the latest version using `brew upgrade gnupg`.

Comment: works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem with pinentry (utility used to register the passphrase). Is it installed on your mac? If not, run `brew install pinentry-mac` and try again, otherwise you need to change your configuration. Check the comment on this [issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/14737) for details but this should be ok:

```
brew install pinentry-mac
echo "pinentry-program /usr/local/bin/pinentry-mac" >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
killall gpg-agent
```

Comment: See @sunknudsen comment for a better approach.